# Classify Data by Method Regardless of Data Range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I want to apply the same classification method to multiple Rasters in ModelBuilder Reclassify tool. The task is to apply the same classification method (percentile splits) across multiple rasters without setting the data value splits manually as I will always need the same 20/20/20/20/20 split of data.

How do you input a pre-defined classification method automatically e.g. Method: Quantile with 5 classes?

Comment: What have you done so far? Looping over many rasters in model builder is done with a Iterator, suggest you look there first.

Comment: Yes, I will iterate the process after any progress on the above has been made. When using the reclassify tool, the default classification Method is Natural Jenks. I want to change this so by default, Rasters are classified by the Quantile method with 5 breaks.